# MySQL: sum values from subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Is it possible to sum two values from subqueries?

I need select three values: total_view, total_comments and rating.

Both subqueries is very complicated, so i don't wish duplicate it.

My query example:

```
SELECT p.id,
(
    FIRST subquery  
) AS total_view,
(
    SECOND subquery 
) AS total_comments,
(
    total_view * total_comments
) AS rating
FROM products p
WHERE p.status = "1"
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: No. Not without constructing a wrapper query around all of that. But MySQL doesn't care about 'complicated ', so why not write it out longhand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using a subquery:

```
SELECT p.*, (total_view * total_comments) as rating
FROM (SELECT p.id,
             (FIRST subquery) AS total_view,
             (SECOND subquery) AS total_comments,
      FROM products p
      WHERE p.status = '1'  -- if status is a number, then remove quotes
     ) p
ORDER BY rating DESC;
```

MySQL materializes the subquery.  But because the `ORDER BY` is on a computed column, it needs to sort the data anyway, so the materialization is not extra overhead.

Comment: This is the simplest solution I think. It's short to write and efficient to run.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use alias but you can use the same code eg:

```
  SELECT p.id,
  (
      FIRST subquery  
  ) AS total_view,
  (
      SECOND subquery 
  ) AS total_comments,
  (
      (
      FIRST subquery  
    ) * (
      SECOND subquery 
    )
  ) AS rating 

  FROM products p
  WHERE p.status = "1"
  ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: Do you know if MySQL's optimizer is actually smart enough to avoid running the same subquery twice?

Comment: My answer is  strictly related to the question provided ..but anyway  .. yes  . i know ..

Comment: Another question, do you know which release added that? I just tried it on 5.6 and it still runs the subquery twice.

Comment: @dnoeth  The sql optimizer  for subquery  is mainly related to IN or EXISTS ,  FROM() subquery  .and seems .not for the colums subquery as the question prodvided .. for what i remenber there is not appreciable change between  5.6 and 5.7 .. .i'm agree with you that for "column" subquery as in question  .. the better optimiziation is based changing the "column" subquery with a FROM subbquery and so reusing the temp table create by sql engine  .  .. hope is useful  .

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a Derived Table to be able to reuse the aliases:

```
SELECT p.id,
   total_view,
   total_comments,
   total_view * total_comments AS rating
FROM
 (
   SELECT p.id,
    (
        FIRST subquery  
    ) AS total_view,
    (
        SECOND subquery 
    ) AS total_comments
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.status = "1"
 ) as dt
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @TheImpaler: It wasn't me using double quotes, it was copied from the OP. If `status` is a numeric column it should be without any quotes :-)